# gwt-atmosphere demo nullpointer lookup broadcaster

Tags: gwt, atmosphere

firstly thank for demo.
i have bean downloaded demo right now and i tried to test i got an error
what is wrong and i cant understant "MyBroadcaster" defined where.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.atom.rpc.server.GwtRpcAtmosphereHandler.doPost(GwtRpcAtmosphereHandler.java:58)
    at com.atom.rpc.server.GwtRpcAtmosphereHandler.onRequest(GwtRpcAtmosphereHandler.java:38)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:239)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:165)
    at org.atmosphere.container.JettyCometSupport.service(JettyCometSupport.java:96)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1725)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:198)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
[ERROR] 500 - POST /GwtRpcDemo/atmosphere/rpc?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=3107f259-ace2-4384-bd18-647e417b58c4&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.0.5-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=polling&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=text/x-gwt-rpc;%20charset=UTF-8&_=1384597532735
```

thanks for replay.

Comment: Please post some code, or at least a link to the demo you are trying to run.

Comment: i solved with lookup("/*"). sometimes lookup("MyBroadcaster") it works but sometimes not. i get another problem, when i started project and send message server listend but not broadcast. i tested it with 2 borowser window isend a message but other not aware of anythink. am i wrong?

Comment: Again: Please provide more context or at least a link to the demo.. ;)